# Parse related Error while building Unity project for iOS (Culture name neutral is not supported)

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, sigabrt, il2cpp

I've been trying to build my game for iOS for a week now and figured I'd just ask for help. I've got it working on Android and Windows Phone.

**Details:**
Version : Unity 5.1.1p2

I'm building a Development build from Unity with Script debugging turned on.

Scripting backend : IL2Cpp
Architection: Universal
SDK Version: Simulator SDK

Xcode:
Xcode version 6.3.2
iOS deployment target 7.1
iPhone Simulator SDK 8.3

Parse version:
1.5.2

The application builds fine. But once it starts running on the simulator, it breaks with an Il2CppExceptionWrapper:

From the stack, I can tell that this breaks during ParseInitializeBehavior. Here's what I see in the stack trace, outer to inner:

1. ParseInitializeBehavior_Awake
2. ParseInitializeBehavior_Initialize
3. ParseClient
4. ParseClient_get_Version()
5. ParseName   ---  in this function the value for ___assemblyName is : Parse.Unity, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
6. CultureInfo_CreateCulture  (name = "neutral")
7. CultureInfo_ctor
8. CultureInfo_ConstructInternalLocaleFromName

Raises **"Culture name neutral is not supported"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because this problem went away.

The issue appears fixed in Parse 1.5.3 for Unity.

Comment: Hi I am really newbie in unity world, how should I change the parse version to 1.5.3?

Answer (score 0):

The type Il2CppExceptionWrapper is used by IL2CPP to wrap managed exceptions in C++ exceptions. You can set an exception breakpoint in Xcode when an exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper is thrown, then inspect the exception to determine its cause. There is some information about how to do this in Xcode here:

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/20/il2cpp-internals-debugging-tips-for-generated-code/

Comment: Thanks! That was really useful. I was able to debug the exception - updated my question above. I'm getting an exception in the Parse plugin saying that the Culture name "neutral" is not supported.

Comment: Does the blank Parse project happen to work? This looks like something that happens for any Parse project. Maybe there is a setting in Unity related to stripping or the .NET profile which causes a problem here.

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed in Parse 1.5.3. Thanks for your help!